# zinit:integer:7: IFS: can't change type of a special parameter

Tags: zsh, zshrc

When I place some plugins like:

```
zinit light zdharma/fast-syntax-highlighting
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-completions
```

the mac terminal gives this message

```
zinit:integer:7: IFS: can't change type of a special parameter
```

Comment: One of the plugins apparently tries something like `typeset -i IFS`, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to follow some steps of this article - https://medium.com/@isaacmeira/como-usar-um-terminal-unix-com-myzsh-spaceship-e-zplugin-no-windows-e-vscode-7d801ce60064